# Compute an adjacency matrix efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a recommendation dataset that I have transformed into a matrix of the form:

```
           item1       item2     item3 ...
user1       NaN         2.3       NaN
user2       1.7         3.4       NaN
user3       NaN         1.1       2.6
...
```

where `NaN` are items that the particular user has not reviewed yet. The above is in the form of a pandas dataframe. I want to construct an adjacency matrix from this, based on a predefined distance metric. I have a working function:

```
def compute_adjacency_matrix(reccomender_matrix):
    # replace nan with 0
    rec_num = reccomender_matrix.fillna(value=0)

    # compute the distances between every two users
    result = np.array([[compute_distance(li[2:], lj[2:]) for lj in rec_num.itertuples()] for li in rec_num.itertuples()])
    adjacency_matrix = (result > 0.0).astype(int)

    return adjacency_matrix
```

the problem is that, for large matrices, the line that computes `result` takes very long. What is the most efficient way of doing this, that would scale for larger datasets?

**EDIT**: Here is the compute distance function:

```
def compute_distance(vec1, vec2):
    rez =  sum(abs(v1[(v1>0)&(v2>0)] - v2[(v1>0)&(v2>0)]))
    norm = np.count_nonzero(v1) if np.count_nonzero(v1) < np.count_nonzero(v2) else np.count_nonzero(v2)
    norm_rez = rez / norm
    return norm_rez
```

Comment: What does `compute_distance` do? If you can use native numpy broadcasting it will be much faster than looping with `itertuples`. Can you give a sample code for `compute_distance`?

Comment: I added the function above. It takes the distance between two vectors just by their non-zero elements on common positions.

Comment: Regardless of the implementation, I think you need to rethink your metrics and outputs.  That code will make anyone who's recommended the same item adjacent, no matter what score they gave - unless the gave the same scores, then they won't be adjacent.  Not sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you want a mean absolute distance metric, although that's not exactly what you wrote (since you're normalizing not by the size of the intersection but the size of the smaller vector).  If you want mean absolute distance, it's simply:

```
def compute_distance(vec1, vec2):
    return np.nanmean(np.abs(vec1 - vec2))
```

You can then use that metric with `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` and `squareform`

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
def compute_adjacency_matrix(reccomender_matrix):
    result = squareform(pdist(reccomender_matrix.values.T, metric = compute_distance))
    result = np.nan_to_num(result)
    adjacency_matrix = (result > 0.0).astype(int)

    return adjacency_matrix
```

As noted in my comment, I think you need to rethink your metrics and outputs. That code will make anyone who's recommended the same item adjacent, no matter what score they gave - unless the gave the same scores, then they won't be adjacent. Not sure that's what you want.

A slightly better method  would be carrying through the `nan`s and using them to make your adjacency matrix.

```
def compute_adjacency_matrix(reccomender_matrix):
    result = squareform(pdist(reccomender_matrix.values.T, metric = compute_distance))
    adjacency_matrix = np.logical_not(np.isnan(result)).astype(int)
    return adjacency_matrix
```

If you don't need the distances, you can do it all with binary operations:

```
def adjacency(x, y):
    return np.any(np.logical_and(x, y))

def compute_adjacency_matrix(reccomender_matrix):
        return squareform(pdist(np.isfinite(reccomender_matrix.values.T), 
                                metric = adjacency)).astype(int)
```

Finally, you can do it all with `numba` if that's all too slow:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def compute_adjacency_matrix(reccomender_matrix):
    n, m = reccomender_matrix.shape
    out = np.zeros((m, m))
    count = np.zeros((m, m))
    dists = np.zeros((m, m))
    adj = np.zeros((m, m))
    for i in range(1, m):
        for j in range(i + 1, m):
            for k in range(n):
                if not(np.isnan(reccomender_matrix[k, i]) or \
                       np.isnan(reccomender_matrix[k, j])):
                    out[i, j]   += np.abs(reccomender_matrix[k, i] - reccomender_matrix[k, j])
                    count[i, j] += 1
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(m):
            if i == j:
                dists[i, j] = 0.
            elif i < j:
                if count[i, j] != 0:
                    dists[i, j] = out[i, j] / count [i, j]
                    adj[i, j] = 1
                else:
                    dists[i, j] = 0.
            else:
                dists[i, j] = dists[j, i]
                adj[i, j] = adj[j, i]
    return dists, adj
```

Comment: One question: since this code is very slow, do you have any idea how this may be parallelized? I am looking at this: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/#5howtoparallelizeanyfunction  but no clue how to modify the above to fit it.

Comment: Do you want to use the result of `compute_distance` for anything else?  Because otherwise you can just do binary operations which will be much faster.

Comment: No, just for my dataset, but it's slow, and I realized it's only using a single thread, though I have 16 available. I was wondering if I can make it use all available threads.

Also, now that it finished running, the above code (last function) returns False and True, not the distances. That is not the desired result.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot `.astype(int)`, sorry.  Check out the seed on the binary version I added

Comment: Ok, but the last two functions are for the case where I don't care about the distances (edge weights). I will use the first definition of compute_adjacency, as for me the edge weights (distances) are essential.

Comment: The numba implementation throws an error: 

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function zeros>) with argument(s) of type(s): (tuple(int64 x 2), dtype=Function(<class 'float'>))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in function zeros>)

Comment: Yeah, I think I fixed it.  `numba` is a bit of a pain if you're not used to coding in `c` (i'm not)

Comment: Sorry, one more question about the first compute_adjacency matrix. My input dataframe is (610, 9720) with 610 users and 9720 items. The output adjacency matrix is 9720 x 9720. My adjacency matrix should be 610 x 610 (where I look at distances between users based on their preference, not between items). Is this solved by removing that transposed condition ?

Comment: should be.  Sorry, difficult to match shapes without input data

Comment: seems to have worked by just removing the transpose. Thanks